# No Hyphens in SKU Built from Custom Options

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I'd like to prevent hyphens being used when Magento builds SKU's from a product's selected custom options. Does anyone know where this happens in core, and how to override it?

Answer (score 2):

The hyphens is added by the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType::getOptionSku()` method, which usually called from the `getSku()` method :

```
/**
 * Default action to get sku of product
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @return string
 */
public function getSku($product)
{
    $sku = $product->getData('sku');
    if ($product->getCustomOption('option_ids')) {
        $sku = $this->getOptionSku($product, $sku);
    }
    return $sku;
}
```

If you want to completely stop using the hyphens in sku just create an around plugin for the `getOptionSku()` method and return original sku, like:

```
if (empty($sku)) {
    $sku = $product->getData('sku');
}

return $sku;
```

**PS:** I did not test that solution yet, but try to write a simple plugin and update my answer with a result.

Comment: This is differently the place I should be looking, but the plugin isn't affecting the SKU's at all -- not sure what's up.